# How can I link data to a select element in AJAX method?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a problem wherein I cannot put the data inside select element and make an option using the ID to append on what is inside my ajax. I got the data and it is showing in an input element but when I switched it into select element it doesn't work.

Here is the image of my form

[image]

JQuery / Ajax code

```
    function ToolsChange(element) {
    let tools_id = $(element).val();

    if (tools_id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "form_JSON_approach.php",
            data: {
                "tools_id": tools_id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var dataSplit = response;
                console.log(response);
                var shouldSplit = dataSplit.split("@");
                var shouldNotSplit = dataSplit.split();
                console.log(shouldSplit);
                console.log(shouldSplit[0]);
                console.log(shouldSplit[1]);
                console.log(shouldSplit[2]);
                $("#sel_control_num").val(shouldSplit[0]);

                var specs = [];
                for (i = 1; i < shouldSplit.length; i += 3) {
                    specs.push(shouldSplit[i])
                }

                $("#sel_tools_spec").val(specs.join(', '));

                $("#sel_tools_id").val(shouldSplit[2]);
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

HTML code(I had to comment select element because it is not showing the data)

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label> Tools Specification: </label>
     <input id="sel_tools_spec" class="form-control" name="tools_specification"
      data-live-search="true" readonly>
<!-- <select id="sel_tools_spec" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      </select> -->
</div>
```

PHP code

```
    <?php 

    include("../include/connect.php");

 
    if(isset($_POST['tools_id'])){
        
        $ID = $_POST['tools_id'];

        $query = "SELECT tools_masterlist.control_no, tools_masterlist.tools_id, 
        tools_masterlist.tools_name, 
        tools_spec.model_num,tools_spec.model_num_val, tools_spec.status
        FROM tools_masterlist LEFT JOIN tools_spec ON tools_masterlist.tools_id = tools_spec.tools_id
        LEFT JOIN tools_registration ON tools_masterlist.control_no = tools_registration.reg_input 
        WHERE status = 1 AND tools_name = '$ID'";

        $con->next_result();
        // $result=mysqli_query($con, "CALL GetAjaxForToolsRegistration('$ID')");
        $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                // echo $row['control_no'] . "@" . $row['model_num'] . "@" . $row['tools_id'] ."@";
                echo $row['control_no'] . "@" . '<option value="'.$row['tools_id'].'">'. 
                $row['model_num'] .'</option>' . "@" . $row['tools_id'] ."@";
            }
        }
        else
        {
          
        }

    }
  ?>
```

Comment: are you trying to make the `select` selectable or readonly ?

Comment: key is `appendChild`, you are wrong at DOM control

Comment: @tinker selectable :)

Comment: @王仁宏 how should I do it? I am still newbie in Jquery in terms of using method.

Comment: @any_something then you will need unique ID per tool specification right ? At the moment all option have same ID `T-1001`. how will you know which one was selected if all option have same value ?

Comment: Yes my unique ID is T-001. Tools specification is based on my tools name so when I click tools name it shows the data of tools specification.

Comment: @tinker they have the same value as that is there tools id but the model_num is differenr because they are the names of the specified tools

Comment: I don't think you understood what I'm saying. I mean `option` should have unique `value` to know which was selected to pass it to backend. See this example https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_form

Comment: Ahhhh! Okay now I get it sorry, I changed the tools_id it just confused me haha. So the value should be itself based on the link you sent me

Comment: Hi , can you elaborate more on your issue ?

Comment: @Swati, the problem is that when I select data from selection it doesn't show in my tools specification which is a select element too that is why I tried to create html element from ajax to append it in html but the problem is it doesn't show so instead selection I temporarily used input element,the purpose for this is, for example I have a name of my tools and then it needs to specify,now in specifying tools for example ballpen is the tools name and needs to be specified,there are many kinds of ballpen. now if I clicked tools name "ballpen" and its specified tools is three then it should show

Comment: it should show as three "options" inside selection tools specification.

Comment: so currently problem is appending new options inside select-box ?

Comment: yes ma'am @Swati the problem is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending all datas at onces instead inside for-loop you can directly append options inside your `selectpicker` and refresh it.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#sel_tools_spec").selectpicker() //intialize on load
ToolsChange() //just for demo..
function ToolsChange(element) {
  /*let tools_id = $(element).val();

  if (tools_id) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "form_JSON_approach.php",
      data: {
        "tools_id": tools_id
      },
      success: function(response) {*/
  //other codes....
  $("#sel_tools_spec").html('');
  //suppose data look like this...
  var shouldSplit = ["1", "<option>A</option>", "1001", "2", "<option>B</option>", "1001"]
  for (i = 1; i < shouldSplit.length; i += 3) {
    //append options inside select-box
    $("#sel_tools_spec").append(shouldSplit[i]);
  }
  $("#sel_tools_spec").selectpicker('refresh'); //refresh it
  /* }
    });*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet " type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label> Tools Specification: </label>
  <select id="sel_tools_spec" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one more concern, whenever I click a data in tools specification it becomes unclickable. I think because of this  $("#sel_tools_spec").html(''); I tried removing it but when I removed it, it shows error.

Comment: `becomes unclickable..` ? Please elaborate more ? Also , are you seeing that behaviour in above code ?

Comment: I reviewed your code one more. That's why I got error, I misplaced $("#sel_tools_spec").html(''); thanks!

Comment: I see . Let me know if you didn't understood anything from my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to `split()` or even return your response using `echo ... @... @...` .. Ok here is what you should do

The main idea in my code is: returning all the data from php/database
then control it in js/ajax and this will happen by using `dataType : 'json'` and `echo json_encode($data)`

in php

```
$return_result = [];
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
       $return_result[] = $row;
   }
}
else
{
    $return_result['error'] = 'error';      
}
echo json_encode($return_result);
```

in javascript (ajax)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "form_JSON_approach.php",
    dataType : 'json', // <<<<<<<<<<< here
    data: {
        "tools_id": tools_id
    },
    success: function(response) {
       if(!response.error){
         //console.log(response);
         $.each(response , function(index , val){
           // here you can start do your stuff append() or anything you want
           console.log(val.control_no);
           console.log(val.tools_id);
         });
       }else{
         console.log('You Have Error , There is Zero data'); 
       }
     }
});
```

Comment: Why did it returned object object 3 times? I still used the ID in my element and then I used the method .val();

Comment: @any_something did you use my code? if yes its ok make it simple and take it step by step .. `console.log(response);` first and see the result then `console.log(val)` inside `.each` and check again and so on .. and Don't forget to add `dataType : 'json',` to the ajax

Comment: Yes I am trying it right now, will comment to you if something I can't understand. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi sir I tried your code and make it show into input elements however I have confusion on part of select and option how will I append my data there? should I create an option inside my ajax and linked it to the id on my select?

Comment: @any_something yes something like `$('#your_select_here').append('<option value="'+val.tools_id+'">'+val.tools_id+'</option>')`

Comment: I have other question, since I did not use split and it is the same when it comes to output. The problem is the append, where if I click the first tools name "Air blower" its tools specification comes out but when I clicked another tools name it appends its value, How should I trap it so that this will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap. Just do the following

```js
$("#sel_tools_spec").empty().append('<option value="ID">LABEL</option>').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Source: [how to append options in select bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044074/how-to-append-options-in-select-bootstrap)

Comment: Thanks! :) . However whenever I click other tools name it stacks tools specification information to the first. is selectpicker('refresh') the code that I need so that whenever I click it it should refresh?

Comment: what do you mean ? the first select option is dialed in ?

Comment: empty the select menu first then. Would be `$("#sel_tools_spec").empty().append('<option value="ID">LABEL</option>').selectpicker('refresh');`

Comment: The selection is working, when I click 1st option it shows the three datas that is under tool specification and that is what I am expecting, but when I try to click other data in tools masterlist selection, the tools specification of it is dialed/appended in, it should not append. I don't know how should I trap it.

Comment: yes I tried that but when I clicked it, it shows only 1 data in the 1st select option.

Comment: that would be another question all together.

Comment: Ahhh okay I should post another question. Thank you very much @tinker

Comment: @tinker Hi, why giving downvote ? Please specify reason.

Comment: @Swati Stack overflow is place for people to help learn programming. I don't see will for asker to learn programming. when they don't even understand basic constructs like `loops` the answer like yours above discourages people to think themself  and hence learn programming fundamentals.

Comment: Then say that in comment no need to put downvote . Also , op has already tried himself he/she was not able to achieve that's why he/she has ask question here  . If there is something wrong with my answer i understand you put downvote . That's , so unfair on ppl here giving answer to get downvote for no reason.